# Totem sidebar gone after upgrade (playlist)

Tags: 15.04, totem

I just noticed that my totem video player doesn't have a sidebar with playlist anymore.

I didn't use totem for some time, so I am not sure which ubuntu upgrade was responsible for it, now I am using vivid.

Is there any way to get the sidebar back including the playlist?

If not, what were the reasons to remove the playlist sidebar?

**Edit**

`apt-cache policy totem` gives

```
totem:
  Installed: 3.14.3-0ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 3.14.3-0ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.14.3-0ubuntu0.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.14.2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I'm wondering too. Without it, it's impossible to queue a bunch of files. I would like to add that such an essential feature has always been present in *any* player software for decades. Should I ask what's going on with crazy "modern" trends ?

Comment: Maybe the side bar thing is now a plugin?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2278673 Have you tried this ?

Comment: @kenn Thanks, but I don't want to use smplayer. The gesttings thing doesn't work.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy totem`

Comment: I noticed this issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, and and even reported it as [bug #1600606](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1600606). But it turns out this was an intended feature reversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no sidebar anymore in Totem. There is only the overview, which you can see, if you start Totem, or use the arrow button in the upper left corner if you have started a video.

[image]

You could add the menubar via

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides '{"Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu":<0>}'
```

[image: dc]

but not the sidebar.

Reset with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides '{}'
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference to a changelog or a discussion between the totem developers of that, when and why the feature vanished from the code?

Comment: Currently the only answer that will handle the actual problem. +1@A.B

Comment: @student sorry, no. Since GNOME 3.14 there is a fundamental redesign. Some people like it, some people not. There is a IRC on Freenode.net. where you can talk with the developers. https://wiki.gnome.org/Community/GettingInTouch/IRC

Comment: A rather arrogant way to deal with the users, simply stop offering them a playlist. thanks for informing though.

Comment: In 3.10.1 under 14.04 I used the sidebar extensively to display video properties of the currently running movie. This is the functionality I miss the most. Having to open a poorly sized properties window over the top of the current movie, blocking the action and then having to resize it to read the info adds insult to injury. Do you know of any plugin that would return that functionality or any alternative approach?

Comment: So bad. I loved the totem sidebar.

Comment: The documentation still lists F9 to open the playlist: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/totem.1.html - which of course doesn't do anything.