# How to revert back to a full featured Totem release?

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, totem

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 I noticed that Totem (the default video player) is [no longer portraying its sidebar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653436/totem-sidebar-gone-after-upgrade-playlist), which includes the much useful stack playlist. I judged this to be [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1600606), but it turns out this was a conscientious regression introduced by the software developers.

Therefore I am looking for an easy way to get back to an earlier Totem release. This could either be with a fork, say, a [Nemo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_(file_manager)) counterpart to Totem, or through an earlier full featured release (which I believe to have been 3.12) available from a PPA.

Comment: Same awful decision happened to Gedit, all the useful buttons were removed in favour of three small strange and ugly ones and much free space in the tool bar... Here's a question about downgrading Gedit - it won't be directly applicable, but maybe you can adapt the procedures there to your needs: http://askubuntu.com/q/766055/367990

Comment: An older totem with sidebar ect. would not be practicable & likely impossible to use in 16.04. No where near what was involved in using an older gedit which is in a ppa for 16.04. You should look for an alternate media player to suit your taste & use case.

Comment: This may suit you, in an ubuntu session a log out may be needed for it to show in the Dash. A search of xplayer or Videos should work. For some dumb reason the Name= in the xplayer.desktop is Videos, ie. the same as totem's. (- icon is different, it's the old one) - https://launchpad.net/~trebelnik-stefina/+archive/ubuntu/nero-linux

Comment: I see another ppa, newer, seems much better - https://launchpad.net/~embrosyn/+archive/ubuntu/xapps

Comment: doug, yours is the right answer. Would you please insert it?